# is keychain in ios threadsafe?

Tags: ios, thread-safety, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I would like to add some items to the keychain using "secitemadd", but I need to know first, if this is thread safe.

I have read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Attribute_Item_Keys) from apple, but I am unable to find anywhere stating if its thread-safe.

Comment: I am amazed how little documentation there is on this. I would imagine that based on the lack of documentation and issues raises on SO, that the API is probably thread safe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In another document, Apple says it is thread safe.

> Concurrency Considerations
> On iOS, all the functions in this API are thread-safe and reentrant.

see [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/working_with_concurrency)

Comment: Quinn explains concurrency in Keychain a bit more in depth in this forum post, might be of interest to anyone looking into this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117092?answerId=361922022#361922022

Answer (score 1):

Keychain isn't thread-safe. If we try to retrieve the keychain information it returns `-25300` from time to time in practice. Be careful.

Comment: `-25300` = errSecItemNotFound to help those reading; also this answer is only partially accurate -- the accepted answer is accurate.  macOS and iOS are **different**.  Here, the question clearly states _ios_ thus this answer is incorrect.

Comment: It may be helpful noting [there are other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721826/keychain-error-25300-errsecitemnotfound-when-disabling-and-re-enabling-touch) that can cause similar result code.

Comment: @Mark and what? the question of what about thread saving. Not about any other reason of -25300.

Comment: @Vyacheslav  read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/working_with_concurrency)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Apple docs state "In iOS, all the functions in this API are thread-safe and reentrant." this is in the Security framework and keychain is part of this framework. I have posted the link above. [This is the link to the apple docs once again](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/working_with_concurrency?language=objc). May I ask what your reference is?

Comment: @Alhomaidhi I faced the problem where this isn't correct.